# How to remove last octet of an ip address in terminal?

Tags: bash, debugging, terminal, isolation

Lets say I have an IP address of `123.456.789.01`

I want to remove the last octet 123.456.789.**01** but not the period.

So what I have left is `123.456.789.`

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Linux Terminal

I tried isolating the final octet but that just gives me the last octet `01` not `123.456.789.`:

```
$ address=123.456.789.01 
$ oct="${address##*.}"
$ echo "$oct"
01
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With string manipulation, you cannot use lookarounds like in regex, but you can simply put the dot back once it is removed since it is a fixed pattern part.

You can use

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='123.456.789.01'
s="${s%.*}."
echo "$s"
# => 123.456.789.
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/s6pezq).

Note that `${s%.*}` removes the shortest string to the first `.` from the end of string.

Answer (score 5):

@WiktorStribiżew has the right answer.

A couple of other (more esoteric) techniques:

- since `${address##*.}` removes up to the last dot, leaving the octet, we can remove *that* from the end of the string:

  ```bash
  echo "${address%${address##*.}}"    # => 123.456.789.
  ```
- using the `extglob` shell option, we enable [extended patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) and can remove the longest sequence of *one or more* digits from the end of the string

  ```bash
  shopt -s extglob
  echo "${address%%+([0-9])}"
  # or, with a POSIX character class
  echo "${address%%+([[:digit:]])}"
  ```